# Datatable rowReordering prevent certain row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have simple DataTable and i would like to prevent user to drag last row in table (in this case Test 6) and to prevet him to add any row after that 6th row. So last row should always remain there as last. Is anything like this possible with their API ? Or what should i do?

Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="launch_cpa_table">
<thead class="bg-info">
    <th class="text-white">Step</th>
    <th class="text-white">Name</th>
    <th class="text-white">Gate</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td>Test 1</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Test 2</td>
        <td>Test 2</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Test 3</td>
        <td>Test 3</td>
    </tr> 
     <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Test 4</td>
        <td>Test 4</td>
    </tr> 
     <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Test 5</td>
        <td>Test 5</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr style = 'background : gray'>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Test 6</td>
        <td>Test 6</td>
    </tr> 

</tbody>
```

JS:

```
 var launch_table = $('#launch_cpa_table').DataTable( {
    rowReorder: true,
    columnDefs: [
        { orderable: true, className: 'reorder', targets: [0] },
        { orderable: false, targets: '_all' }
    ],
    paging: false
} );
```

FiddleJs link:
https://jsfiddle.net/5r6u7z02/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is anwer to my question :

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/163982#Comment_163982

Answer (score 0):

You can use `orderable: false` in `columnDefs`, this help you to avoid this `row` to `drag`. just add `no-sort` class to your `row`

```
columnDefs: [{
    targets: 'no-sort',
    orderable: false
  }
],
```

Maybe this not work on any version, but there is a trick solution, use `pointer-events: none`

<kbd>[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcbdemn3/1/)</kbd>

Comment: This is correct but this does not solve my problem at all mate. I wanted to prevent user to drag any row bellow row Test 6. I posted solution so you can take a look how it should work. Thanks for reply by the way! @pedram